# Looping in /etc/default/grub when running dpkg --configure -a

Tags: grub2, dpkg

I can't finish installing the packages on my system, when I run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, receive this:

```
'Setting up friendly-recovery (0.2.39ubuntu0.19.04.1) ...
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
```

So I get stuck in the loop.

Output for the command `diff -s /etc/default/grub /usr/share/grub/default/grub`:

```
9c9
< GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="button.lid_init_state=open intel_idle.max_cstate=4"
---
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
33,36d32
< sudo update-grub && sudo reboot
< 
< update-grub
<
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

DPKG is trying to [source](http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/04/what-is-sourcing-file.html?m=1) the GRUB but because of presence of

```
sudo update-grub && sudo reboot

update-grub
```

from line number 32 to 36, GRUB file is getting sourced recursively. If it were some other command, your system would have been rebooted before *actually* sourcing the GRUB completely because of `sudo reboot`. But because of `sudo update-grub` you ended up in infinite recursion. In a nutshell, the command looks like:

```
update-grub(){
    update-grub
}
```

You need to edit the GRUB file and remove line number 32 to 36, i.e., which has `update-grub`. To edit run

```
sudoedit /etc/default/grub
```

Remove the lines and save. Once done, try running

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

or

```
sudo update-grub
```