# I can't install/uninstall .deb packages because dpkg is being interrupted

Tags: command-line, grub2, dpkg, deb

Whenever I try to install/uninstall any `.deb` packages I got this error:

```
dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a'
```

When I run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, then the `/etc/default/grub` goes into an loop:

Output:

```
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.15.0-53-generic (5.15.0-53.59) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.15.0-53-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-53-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
```

I tried this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164196/dpkg-configure-causing-endless-sourcing-of-etc-default-grub) but it wasn't useful because I didn't had any number in it.
When I'm running `sudoedit /etc/default/grub` receive:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=1
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"


# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: `mkdir $HOME/backup`  and `sudo  mv /etc/default/grub $HOME/backup` Restore default file with `sudo cp /usr/share/grub/default/grub /etc/default/grub` and try your dpkg command again.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to solve it for hours, but your solution really helped!